# What is the word for "Bar" progress and write it in python script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, pyscripter

I am a beginner in python and have written a few scripts and I am wondering if there is a term for python to call and show the progress of the bar telling you from start to finish like you see in geoprocessing at the lower right corner in ArcMap ?

Answer (score 7):

A good starting point to understanding this is a help page entitled [Understanding the progress dialog box in script tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Understanding_the_progress_dialog_box_in_script_tools/00150000002w000000/):

> There are four functions you use to control the progress dialog box
>   and its progressor.

This certainly works for foreground Geoprocessing and I assume that it will have a similar effect on the Background Geoprocessing dialog.